# Jenkins Git SSH keys on Windows slave

Tags: git, jenkins

We currently have a Jenkins master on Windows, an ubuntu slave, and a Windows slave.  I'm trying to set up git on the Windows slave.  msysgit is installed, and I included the directory in the system path variable so that I can call "git.exe" or "git.cmd" anywhere.

In my Jenkins configuration, I have a credential with a private SSH key.  This credential is for Jenkins to use with Git.  This works on the master node and the linux slave.  I did not put the private ssh key on either of those two servers, Jenkins handled it for me.

But the Windows slave, not so much.  When I run a job on the windows slave, all I get is `ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'`.

How can I get the credential working on the Windows slave?  Or, if you don't think that's the issue, what would be my next troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you seen any other messages after this error, could you update your question to include them?

Without seeing them, I can only suspect that git on your Windows slave cannot find the `.ssh` folder (this folder contains your keys).

Have you already looked at the notes on the [Git Plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)?

Comment: There are no other errors in the job, or the slave log.  You say you suspect it can't find the `.ssh` folder where the keys would be, I assume that would be under the user's home directory.  There is a `.ssh` folder, but no keys inside.  This is the same as the master node as well.  The private key I want to use is in the Jenkin's credential.

Comment: I also don't think it's a file system permissions issue.  The user Jenkins is running as has full control of the drive I'm trying to clone the repo to.

Comment: Oh shoot.  I restarted the service on the slave, now everything is happy.  Rebooting fixes everything...  sigh.

Comment: I am glad it's working for you. It might be a good idea to review your setup now that it's working -- just so that you can build a checklist in case things stop working in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use C:\Program Files\git\Cmd\git.exe as the git environment variable for the windows slave configuration in Jenkins.

1) Manage Jenkins
2) Manage Nodes
3) Select Windows slave -> go to configuration
4) Add Environment variables for GIT as above complete path.

Also, go to global security settings -> Enable Slave -> Master.

This should work.

Cheers,
Ashoka.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create and fill the ssh folder in the home folder of the windows service at C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.

Source: https://www.techcoil.com/blog/home-directory-of-the-localsystem-account-in-windows-server-2012/

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue. The solution is adding below line to .ssh/config, it lets ssh support rsa again. The key no need to put to .ssh. Jenkins will handle the key from master side.

PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa